# How to hook to server updates (comet ajax) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, comet

[Comet programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is almost known to any web developer, and jQuery is the most popular JavaScript library on the market now. Right?

Now, imagine that there is a service on the server that pushes data to the client every second. The ASP.NET implementation of server code based on C# language might be something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    Response.Write("{data: 'data from server'}");
    Response.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Also imagine that after page loaded into browser, a jQuery snippet triggers a kept-alive HTTP ajax connection with the server, on which server sends those data snippets back to the client.

Up to here is not a problem at all, as a kid developer can do it too. However, jQuery AJAX has many callback functions that get triggered on different occasions. `success`, `error`, `complete`, etc. But none of these methods would get fired on each JSON sent from the server. I mean, this code doesn't work:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'url-of-that-service',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            /*
            Here, I need to get the result sent by 
            the Server, and based on its data, 
            manipulate DOM. For example, imagine
            that server sends its current time
            in JSON format each second. I need
            to parse the sent JSON string, and 
            append the server time somewhere in
            the web page.
            Success function never gets fired for
            these server-pushed data.
            What should I do?
            */
        },
        error: function (error) { }
    });
});
```

One way to get notified about latest updates in jQuery is to poll the `responseText` of the underlying `xhr` object, and periodically check it for the latest data sent by the server. However, I'm looking for an event-based approach to hook into alive ajax connection, and get notified whenever server sends something.

My question is, how should I detect that something has arrived from server? Is there any neat way not including `setTimeout` or `setInterval`? Does jQuery has something to help us here?

Answer (score 0):

You have function, say, `sendCometRequest` where you send ajax request. You can use recursion instead of `setInterval` on success callback you call `sendCometRequest` again after you proceed response from server. It calls as long-polling method. For C# you can read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27107/Scalable-COMET-Combined-with-ASP-NET). It explains a good way for async comet server.

Comment: I need to implement it as a [*pushlet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Pushlet) not as a *long-polled* succession of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Well many things are not clear in your question..

But if you are looking for comet... I think you should look for a solid and practical implementation of comet and avoid doing a [ thread.sleep()+ continuous polling ] kind of hack, as it will not be salable for many simultaneous users.

For .net you have - lightstreamer - http://www.lightstreamer.com/

And, make sure that you really need comet otherwise try using web-sockets.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm already familiar with ready-made solutions to comet programming. However, this time I need to implement it from scratch. **Web-Sockets** or **Server-Sent Events** might be good alternatives. But I don't have enough time to learn them and tackle their unknown problems and challenges.

Comment: Web-sockets are fairly easy to use